# Express route not getting called when url param is not passed

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following code in my server.js for route middleware:

```
app.use('/users', require('./routes/user.routes'));
app.use((req, res) => res.status(404).json({code: 404, message: 'HTTP 404 Not Found'}));
```

And following is my user.routes.js code

```
router.get('/admin/:id', (req, res) => {
    return userController.findUserById(req, res);
});
```

It works fine as long as I give : **localhost:8080/users/admin/123**
But when I give the url without id **localhost:8080/users/admin/**

it sends me this message : `{"code":404,"message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}`

In my opinion it should direct me to proper route. Am I missing something?

Comment: You have `router.get('/user/:id'` as a route. Using the `:id` means that you can access this page with the specific user ID, missing it would not allow you to see it.

Comment: Ok so how do I make it to redirect to /user/ even if id is not present.

Comment: If you have a single admin, then yeah sure you should just delete the `:id` and make it `router.get('/admin` but if you have multiple **admins**, you should keep the `id` section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can get this to work by providing a custom validator:

```
router.get('/admin/:id(\\d{0,})', (req, res) => {
    ...
});
```

My validator checks that the `id` is 0 or more numbers, which will match an empty string. If your `id` is not numeric then you'll have to adapt the regex accordingly. Note that Express uses a special regex syntax which has slightly different rules from normal JavaScript RegExp, for example in Express 4 you can't use use `*` so I've had to use `{0,}` instead (see https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2495).

**Update**

Using a `?` as suggested by Mohit Bhardwaj is a simpler solution but there are slight differences between the approaches. Using the validator I suggested above you will still receive an `id` param but it will be an empty string, whereas with `?` the `id` will not be present in the `params` at all. Whether or not this matters will depend on how you use it.

It is also worth noting that using a `?` will also allow `/users/admin` to match, without the trailing slash.

If you don't care about validating the `id` string as part of route matching then I think using `?` would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info in the update (differences between using a ? and custom validator)...

Comment: this is just the best answer: `router.get('/admin/:id?'`
using the regexp pattern above, it still won't work when it doesn't end with a slash

Answer (score 10):

If you want to have `id` parameter optional, you can add a `?` after it in your route handler:

```
router.get('/admin/:id?', (req, res) => {
    return userController.findUserById(req, res);
});
```

Now, both `/admin/123` and `/admin` will hit this same route. 
But your code might fail if there is no `id` passed along. If this is the case, you should specify 2 different routes:

```
router.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
    return userController.findUserById(req, res);
});


router.get('/admin/:id?', (req, res) => {
    return userController.findDefaultUser(req, res);
});
```

Comment: this works perfectly, no need for a regexp in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The route now expects an id after /user/ (even if there is a /user route), so if there is no ID you will get the 404 Error. A nice way to fix this, is by using `/user/detail/:id` as route. Now it doesn't conflict with the user route.

Comment: I have edited the code above to incorporate what you said, still the same message

Comment: Now you have the `/admin` route and the `/admin/:id` route right? That still doesn't fix it. For the page with ID put something like `/detail`. So like this `/admin/detail/:id`

Comment: I dont have the /admin route

Comment: Then it should work if you pass an ID, but without ID the route won't be initialized

Comment: Thats what my question is. How do I make the controller to pass to this(users/admin/) route even If I dont pass id?